# Защита регистрации на сайте от специальных созданий аккаунтов через http запросы

Tags: auth, nestjs, jwt

Когда пишут простую регистрацию *(логин, пароль и т.д)* данные же как сохраняются. Пользователь вводит свои авторизационные данные, на фронте их получают и через http запрос кидают на бекенд, и там уже происходит сохранение в базу данных. Но любой пользователь может посмотреть куда уходит запрос через браузер и тело запроса. Потом зайти, например, в `Postman` *(сервис для тестирования api)* и отправлять кучу запросов на сервер, и создавать много аккаунтов. Как можно защититься от такого? Добавить какие нибудь уникальные поля? Или, например, email и/или телефон сделать обязательными?

Comment: Капча же ещё есть

Comment: Рассмотрите возможность работы на сайте вообще без создания аккаунта. Подумайте, он в самом деле нужен посетителю вашего сайта?

Answer (score 0):

**Во-первых**, в любом случае Вам необходимо иметь уникальное поле - это может быть почта/номер телефона/никнейм.
*Никнейм обычно используют в связке с почтой или номером телефона* (с подтверждением), что добавляет сложности злоумышленнику (Не получится создать много аккаунтов, не имея большого пула номеров и доступом к ним).

**Во-вторых**, имея "защиту" в виде уникального номера, *ни один сервис не защищен он создания "кучи" аккаунтов*.

Другой способ обезопасить себя от большого количества аккаунтов, использовать `OAuth2`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , мне нужно чтобы какой нибудь человек не мог зайти в postman или другой сервис и просто кидать запросы и создавать кучу аккаунтов которыми никто не пользуется , т.к аккаунт хранятся в базе данных , зачем мне там куча левых аккаунтов

Comment: Пользователь не сможет создать много аккаунтов, если он уже зарегистрирован на свой номер.

А отправку через постман невозможно полностью предотвратить. Только если Вы сами не будете фильтровать людей и вручную создавать им аккаунты.

Comment: У меня маленький сайт который не требует номера телефона и почты , там всего два поля (login , password) все было хорошо , до недавнего времени , решил зайти в базу данных , а там куча созданных аккаунтов почти похожих , потом выяснилось что кто то кидал запросы на сервак и так создавал аккаунты , вот думаем как это пофиксить , может каптчу добавить

Comment: Можете попробовать использовать каптчу, это конечно же помешает создавать кучу аккаунтов, но всё ещё не предотвращает это)